# unordered_set erase not working in C++

Tags: c++, erase, unordered-set

Consider the following situation

```
void first(){

  unordered_set<int> validPorts;
  int roundNum=0, preFunctionSize, postFunctionSize,j=0 ;

  while(j <100){
    if(some_condition_A){
      validPorts.insert(some_int_value);
    }
    j++;
  }

  do{
     preFunctionSize = validPorts.size();
     second( validPorts, some_int_value );
     postFunctionSize = validPorts.size();
  }while(roundNum<12);

}

void second( unordered_set<int> & validPorts, int some_int_value ){

  for (auto it = validPorts.begin(); it != validPorts.end();) {
    if (it == validPorts.find(some_int_value)) {
      validPorts.erase(it++); // <== CODE enters here, I checked
    } else {
      ++it;
    }
  }
}
```

So I expect that the postFunctionSize should be less than the preFunctionSize since I know that it went till the erase function. But it looks like the erase function does not work since i get the same value for the two of them. I am not really sure whats happening here and what is causing it. Can you guys please help me out on what might be wrong with this?

Comment: how is `validPorts` passed to `second()` ? by value? by ref?

Comment: Your code is fine, what compiler do you use ?

Comment: Do you in fact insert `some_int_value` into the set? In other words, does `some_condition_A` evaluate to true for some `j`?

Comment: @PiotrS. Hey I think CashCow has added that missing information :-) Sorry i missed that out. I am actually using systemC compiler 2.3 with gcc 3.4

Comment: @AntonSavin Yes I have checked that. The insertion part works fine, its the erase part thats giving me the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pseudo of course in places but you need to do:

```
it = validPorts.erase( it );
```

in a loop where you are iterating through a collection erasing some of them.

However that is also not really what you want to do. You are trying to erase a value from your `unordered_set` so just do

```
validPorts.erase( some_int_value );
```

and no loop.

Comment: it is equivalent of `validPorts.erase(it++);` ! According to spec: *Only the iterators and references to the **elements removed** are invalidated.*

Comment: @Jarod42: `it++` increments iterator hidden behind `it` variable, but  returns a copy of iterator pointing to previous value.`iterator operator++(int) { iterator copy(*this); ++(*this); return copy; }`